# WPF ListView binding to IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<MyObjectType>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have little problem with DataBinding.
I want to create structure like this:

> ```
> Header
> Item    ItemDetails
> Item    ItemDetails
> Item    ItemDetails
>
> Header
> Item    ItemDetails
> Item    ItemDetails
> ```

So, I have ListView with custom ItemTemplate:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
        <ListView.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1">
                <Grid>
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                  x:Name="PART_AnimatedScrollViewer"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                  Focusable="false">
                                  <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ListView.Template>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" Background="LightGray"/>
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True}">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Here is ViewModel:

```
public class ListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ListViewModel()
    {
        _data.Add("ExampleHeader1", new List<MyObjectType>()
                                              {
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName1", "Description1"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName2", "Description2"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName3", "Description3"),
                                              });
        _data.Add("ExampleHeader2", new List<MyObjectType>()
                                              {
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName1", "Description1"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName2", "Description2"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName3", "Description3"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName4", "Description4"),
                                              });
        _data.Add("ExampleHeader3", new List<MyObjectType>()
                                              {
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName1", "Description1"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName2", "Description2"),
                                                  new MyObjectType("Example ItemName3", "Description3"),
                                              });
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<MyObjectType>> _data = new Dictionary<string, List<MyObjectType>>();
    public IDictionary<string, List<MyObjectType>> Data
    {
        get { return this._data; }
    }

    private KeyValuePair<string, List<MyObjectType>>? selectedKey = null;
    public KeyValuePair<string, List<MyObjectType>>? SelectedKey
    {
        get { return this.selectedKey; }
        set
        {
            this.selectedKey = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedKey");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }

    public List<MyObjectType> SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (null == this.SelectedKey)
            {
                return new List<MyObjectType>();
            }

            return this._data[this.SelectedKey.Value.Key];
        }
        set
        {
            this._data[this.SelectedKey.Value.Key] = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        var eh = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (null != eh)
        {
            eh(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

If I'll run this Application I'll get error:

> Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True}">
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You are trying to add a `DataTemplate` as a child of `ItemsControl`. Apparently, what you wanted to do is this:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Value, IsAsync=True}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks=) I thought that I lost small but important detail.

Comment: @Leonid - It happens, especially at such late hours :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObservableCollection to load the List items.

Even You can change the DataBound control, but it is not recommended. Rather use ObservableCollection and change its content with appropriate list you want to load. As ObservableCollection can easily throw notification to the object where it is bound, your UI list will get updatad.